# How to move window when in compact mode using MediaPlayerElement

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, picture-in-picture

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement`, and using compact mode.

```
<CustomMediaTransportControls
     IsCompactOverlayEnabled="True"
     IsCompactOverlayButtonVisible="True">
</CustomMediaTransportControls>
```

But when enter compact mode, I can't mode the window, because there is no `TitleBar` in compact mode, just a close button.
So anyone know how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you want the titlebar is to minimize the window? When an app window enters compact overlay mode, it’ll be shown above other windows so it won’t get blocked, it seems can't be minimized. You can only click the button in the lower right corner of the image to get back to the normal app layout window and then minimize your window.

**Update:**

If you set `Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);` to define a draggable region, the system shrinks the default draggable region down to a small area the size of a caption button. This means when you enter compact overlay mode, it is actually draggable. The draggable region positioned to the right of the close button but it is a small area. If you want to the rectangle that is the width of the window, the height of the close button can drag, you can pass null as the parameter to SetTitleBar to revert to the default dragging behavior, like `Window.Current.SetTitleBar(null);`

Comment: Not minimize window, actually move the window. Because it seem all uwp apps will compact to right-top, they will overlay. Or my app just block some content behind, user want to move my app to another place when in compact mode.

Comment: Can you upload a gif about you tred to move the window? When I test it, I can move it. In addition, what sample do you use?

Comment: I figure out why you can move the window. I used my own title bar following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar#full-customization-example. Not the original title bar. So in my situation, how to move the window? Thx.